# What happens if I have an endless loop in my rust program?

Tags: rust, performance

I was wondering how in that case the node would know when to kill the process?
Would this increase my compute units and when it reaches the limit it stops? How would the system know about this?
Maybe a timeout? Do you know any sources where I could read about this?

This is a bit not detailed enough:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime

Answer (score 2):

Currently transactions are limited to 1.4M compute units. Usage of compute units is tracked by the runtime. Once a transaction hits that maximum limit, it will simply fail. The signer will still pay a network fee though for submitting the transaction.

Comment: Thank you. But how does the runtime check these compute units? Im wondering about the technicals.

Comment: This part of the codebase is actively being modified. If you want the under-the-hood details, you'll have to codedive: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L53

Comment: I wish I knew more about the runtime honestly, but my understanding is that transactions run in a virtual machine. Different logical operations maps to different compute unit values. As the transactions runs, the compute units are aggregated. If the limit is hit, the transaction is failed.